# Array of linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I was trying to implement array of linked lists. The problem I face is that when I use for loop for traversal, the code throws run time error. Could anyone explain as to why this happens and possible suggestions? 
        // Program to create array of linked lists.

```
     #include <iostream>
     using namespace std;

     struct Node{
       int val;
       Node *next;
     };

     struct Node* insertFirst(struct Node *head, int data){
       struct Node *temp = new Node;
       temp->val = data;
       temp->next = NULL;

       if(head == NULL){
         head = temp;
         return head;
       }
       temp->next=head;

       return temp;
     }

     void traverse(struct Node* head){
       struct Node *list = head;
       if(list == NULL)
         cout<<"List is empty";

       else{
         while(list){
           cout<<list->val<<",";
           list = list->next;
         }
       }
       cout<<endl;    
     }

    int main(){
      struct Node* array[3];

      array[0] = insertFirst(array[0],30);
      array[0] = insertFirst(array[0],20);
      array[0] = insertFirst(array[0],10);

      array[1] = insertFirst(array[1],60);
      array[1] = insertFirst(array[1],50);
      array[1] = insertFirst(array[1],40);


      array[2] = insertFirst(array[2],90);
      array[2] = insertFirst(array[2],80);
      array[2] = insertFirst(array[2],70);

      // Traversal works
      /*traverse(array[0]);
      traverse(array[1]);
      traverse(array[2]);*/

      // Traversal throws run time error.
      for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
         traverse(array[i]);
      }


      return 0;
   }
```

Comment: Always when you get a "runtime error" (also known as a crash) you should run your program in a debugger. It will help you pinpoint where the crash happen, let you examine and walk the function call stack, and also let you examine values of variables.

Comment: Which error? Did you try to debug your code, where exactly does it fail?

Comment: It outputs: 10,20,20,(some random value) and stops

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that local variables, like your array in the `main` function, are not initialized so their values are indeterminate (i.e. random). So when you do

```
array[0] = insertFirst(array[0],30);
```

you pass a non-null value to the function and use that, leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Yep worked :) Thanks a lot.